# Are ElasticSearch scripts safe for concurrency issues?

Tags: elasticsearch, concurrency

I'm running a process which updates user documents on ElasticSearch. This process can run on multiple instances on different machines. In case 2 instances will try to run a script to update the same document in the same time, can there be a case that some of the data will be lost because of a race-condition? or that the internal script mechanism is safe (using the version property for optimistic locking or any other way)?

[The official ES scripts documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the version attribute is safe for that kind of jobs.

Do the search with `version: true`

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "version": true
  your_query...
}
```

Then for the update, add a version attribute corresponding to the number returned during the search.

```
POST /index/type/the_id_to_update/_update?version=3 // <- returned by the search
{
  "doc":{
    "ok": "name"
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/version-control.html

Comment: That is what we were doing until now. The thing here that it required 2 round-trips to the ES cluster. I encountered *ES scripts* (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates) which allow us to send a script defining the change we want to make in one round-trip and reduce the network. The thing is I didn't found any information regarding version-control when using those scripts.